# copy on write and read only files - linux

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, copy-on-write

Suppose I have a single process which has some read-only pages, and it tries to write to one of those pages. This of course will raise a read-fault.

My question is: does linux knows that the read-fault was created due to "real" read-only pages or does it copy the page as if it was created in process duplication?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293157/copy-on-write-vs-illegal-access

Answer (score 0):

Copy-on-write is a deeply in-kernel thing. The user processes see the copy-on-write pages as writable pages. The COW functionality doesn't even activate for readonly pages in the kernel.